# ngAnimate not triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate

I have a modular angular app using ui-router and ngAnimate. After doing some changes to a parent view of my form I ran into a problem where adding a class does not trigger an angular animation.

By lookin at the element I can see that the class 'animate' is being applied, but the class 'ng-animate' which should be added by the ngAnimate module is not beeing applied, thus the animation is not firing. Since I didn't do any modifications to this module, nor are there any console errors I'm stuck with debugging this issue. Animations on other views work fine, the only problem are the animations in this particular view.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    angular.module('app',[
        'ui.router',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngDragDrop',

  // other views
  'app.myView',
        'app.otherView

    ]);
    angular.module('app.myView').animation('showSomething',function(){
        return {
           addClass:function(element,className){
              console.log(className);
           }
        }
    });
  </script>

    <div class="showSomething" ng-class="{'animate':condition}">
        <button ng-click="condition = true">Animate</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: so this does indeed have `angular-animate.js` script loaded, right?

Comment: Yes, it does. I haven't included it inside tho.

Comment: just as a check, what happens if you inject ng-animate directly into your second module..`('app.myView', ['ng-Animate'])`.